# Today Achievements only showing in Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, achievements-dialog

In the Stack Exchange Android app, **Achievements** section I can see only Today's achievements. No Yesterday, Last 7 days, Last 30 days, ... details.

Previously in the 1.0.85 version itself I saw all the achievements.

I  refreshed the page many time, but still seeing Today's achievement only.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Today Achievements only]

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: Motorola
- Device Model: XT1033
- OS Version: 5.1 (2)